# Prove transitivity of relation (defined by  if the arithmetic mean of  and  equals the geometric mean of  and ) on positive real numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

A relation $$ is defined on the set $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ of positive real numbers by $$ if the arithmetic mean of $x$ and $y$ equals the
geometric mean of $$ and $$, that is, if
$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot ( + ) = \sqrt{xy}$$

In order to prove $R$ is an equivalence equation I proved that $R$ is reflexive and symmetric but I am having trouble proving it being transitive.

I supposed $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ such that $xRy$ and $yRz$ and got two equations

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}(x+y)=\sqrt{xy} \\
\frac{1}{2}(y+z)=\sqrt{yz} \\
\end{cases}
$$

but I am struggling to reach $\frac{1}{2}( + z) = \sqrt{z}$, I tried multiplying $\sqrt{z}$ and $\sqrt{x}$ to both side of each equations and substituting but I can't seem to eliminate $y$.

Comment: $R$ is actually, "$=$", the equality. For starters, show that $x+y-2\sqrt{xy}$ is a complete square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about what the relation actually means. Can you find a nontrivial example of two numbers whose arithmetic and geometric means match?

It turns out that the relation isn't actually all that interesting: it's just regular equality. To see this, choose any $x, y > 0$ and observe that:
\begin{align*}
\frac{x + y}{2} = \sqrt{xy}
&\iff x + y = 2\sqrt{xy} \\
&\iff (x + y)^2 = (2\sqrt{xy})^2 \\
&\iff x^2 + 2xy + y^2 = 4xy \\
&\iff x^2 - 2xy + y^2 = 0 \\
&\iff (x - y)^2 = 0 \\
&\iff x - y = 0 \\
&\iff x = y
\end{align*}

So the given relation is transitive because equality is transitive.

Comment: Thank you, these things really make me feel like an idiot